# Rails app using OAuth – how to store token info?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth

I am building a Rails application that needs to be able to send SMS messages. The SMS API that I’m using requires me to login via OAuth.

What would the best practices be for securely storing the user name, password, token and refresh token? I was planning on creating custom Rake tasks that can be run every hour so that the token is always valid.

The app is deployed to Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

Devise with Omniauth could do that -- though it's still not the simplest thing in the world.